# Приложение созданное разработчиком при запуске на симуляторе закрывается сразу после открытия

Tags: ios, xcode, эмулятор

Приложение под iOS собрано разработчиком, у меня только .app файл необходимо запустить его на симуляторе в xcode, но приложение сразу после запуска вылетает, без ошибок, просто на секунду белый экран и сразу закрывается. Попробовал создать свое приложение оно запускается и нормально работает.
Подскажите, с чем может быть проблема, заранее спасибо

В логах внятной ошибки тоже нет

```
ошибка  16:31:07.484925+0300    runningboardd   failed to get pid for label UIKitApplication:com.eugene.EvgSample[5d27][rb-legacy] : No such process (3)
ошибка  16:31:07.485069+0300    runningboardd   Failed to start job for application<com.eugene.EvgSample>: <NSError: 0x7fb5d7619f70; domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain; code: 3; reason: "No such process"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBLaunchdOperation = launch_get_running_pid_4SB;
        RBLaunchdJobLabel = UIKitApplication:com.eugene.EvgSample[5d27][rb-legacy];
    }
}
ошибка  16:31:07.485194+0300    runningboardd   Launchd says label UIKitApplication:com.eugene.EvgSample[5d27][rb-legacy] has never exited
ошибка  16:31:07.486216+0300    SpringBoard Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x7ff94476bda0; application<com.eugene.EvgSample>:-1> with error: <NSError: 0x600001b5e910; domain: RBSRequestErrorDomain; code: 5; reason: "The launchd job couldn't be started."> {
    underlyingError = <NSError: 0x600001b57c30; domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain; code: 3; reason: "No such process"> {
        userInfo = {
            RBLaunchdOperation = launch_get_running_pid_4SB;
            RBLaunchdJobLabel = UIKitApplication:com.eugene.EvgSample[5d27][rb-legacy];
        }
    };
}
ошибка  16:31:07.486399+0300    SpringBoard No exit context returned for failed launch! <FBApplicationProcess: 0x7ff94476bda0; application<com.eugene.EvgSample>:-1>
ошибка  16:31:08.220590+0300    runningboardd   failed to get pid for label UIKitApplication:com.eugene.EvgSample[8302][rb-legacy] : No such process (3)
ошибка  16:31:08.220724+0300    runningboardd   Failed to start job for application<com.eugene.EvgSample>: <NSError: 0x7fb5d761bd20; domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain; code: 3; reason: "No such process"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBLaunchdOperation = launch_get_running_pid_4SB;
        RBLaunchdJobLabel = UIKitApplication:com.eugene.EvgSample[8302][rb-legacy];
    }
}
ошибка  16:31:08.220840+0300    runningboardd   Launchd says label UIKitApplication:com.eugene.EvgSample[8302][rb-legacy] has never exited
ошибка  16:31:08.221857+0300    SpringBoard Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x7ff9453bbf70; application<com.eugene.EvgSample>:-1> with error: <NSError: 0x600001a67300; domain: RBSRequestErrorDomain; code: 5; reason: "The launchd job couldn't be started."> {
    underlyingError = <NSError: 0x600001a676c0; domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain; code: 3; reason: "No such process"> {
        userInfo = {
            RBLaunchdOperation = launch_get_running_pid_4SB;
            RBLaunchdJobLabel = UIKitApplication:com.eugene.EvgSample[8302][rb-legacy];
        }
    };
}
ошибка  16:31:08.221961+0300    SpringBoard No exit context returned for failed launch! <FBApplicationProcess: 0x7ff9453bbf70; application<com.eugene.EvgSample>:-1>
```

Небольшое уточнение? если компилировать  у меня то все запускается и работает, но при переносе app. файла от разработчика запускаться перестает

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте посмотреть вывод в приложении Консоль, там слева в списке будет название запущенного симулятора.

Одна из возможных причин вылета - приложение скомпилировано для более новой версии iOS, чем имеется на симуляторе, также по моим наблюдениям приложение (`app`) не запустится, если его вытащить из пакета архива (`xcarchive`), в то время как если его взять из папки Products после компиляции под симулятор, запускается без проблем на симуляторе с подходящей версией системы после установки через `xcrun simctl install`

Comment: Забавно то, что запускается оно везде кроме машины тестеров :) Машина у тестера: `Intel + Monterey + Xcode 14.2`;  сборка проводилась на: `Intel + Ventura + Xcode 14.3` => fail, `Intel + Ventura + Xcode 14.2` => fail, `Intel + Monterey + Xcode 14.2` => fail, `arm64 + Ventura + Xcode 14.3` => fail, `arm64(emu) + Monterey + Xcode 14.2` => fail. А у меня на всех этих сборках работает в симуляторе приложение собранное на всех сборках, например: `arm64+Ventura+Xcode14.3 => запуск на Intel+Monterey+Xcode14.2` => success :) Причем передавал: Application.app.zip, Product.zip, DerivedData.zip